Rank rows based on multiple text columns in a Google Sheet
I have a table like so:



country
state
name
order




one
two
three



one
two
four



one
five
six



one
five
seven



eight
nine
ten



eight
nine
eleven



eight
nine
twelve




I want an arrayformula to show the rank of name within country and state after name has been sorted.
For example, the expected output would be:



country
state
name
order




one
two
three
2


one
two
four
1


one
five
six
2


one
five
seven
1


eight
nine
ten
2


eight
nine
eleven
1


eight
nine
twelve
3



Also, it is not assured that any of the rows/columns are sroted in the source table.

Use map to calculate all results at once:
=let(
countries,A2:A,
states,B2:B,
names,C2:C,
map(countries,states,names,lambda(each_country,each_state,each_name,
ifna(match(each_name,sort(filter(names,countries=each_country,states=each_state)),0)))))


Thank you so much! I didn't think of using MAP. Good idea!

Assuming that in your example, the column title Country is in A1, this is the formula you'd want in D2, then drag down.
=match(C2,sort(filter(C:C,A:A=A2, B:B=B2)),0)
FILTER() gets all names for the current row's country and state.
SORT() sorts this list of names.
MATCH() finds the current name within the sorted list of names.

Any way to do this with array formula?

Ugh! You did specify you wanted an array formula. My bad. I'll leave this answer up for others' benefit but if I answer with an array formula I'll add it as a separate answer.
